# how to create bitmap in C and compile with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, bitmap

i decided to learn C, and i try to follow this tutorial http://ricardolovelace.com/creating-bitmap-images-with-c-on-windows.html

but when i try to compile my code with gcc as this >gcc -Wall testc o app

he doesn't know type_rgb, can i define this type and how? and where in my code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct rgb_data {
  float r, g, b;
};

void save_bitmap( const char *file_name, int width, int height, int dpi, type_rgb  *pixel_data); 
/*
 next steps of the tutorial
*/

rgb_data *pixels = new rgb_data[width * height];

for( int x = 0; x < width; x++)
  {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        int a = y * width +x; 
          {

            if ((x > 50 && x < 350) && (y > y && y < 350))
              {
                pixels[a].r = 255;
                pixels[a].g = 255;
                pixels[a].b = 0;
              }else{
                pixels[a].r = 55;
                pixels[a].g = 55;
                pixels[a].b = 55;
              }

     }
}

save_bitmap("black_border.bmp", width, height, dpi, pixels);
```

Comment: Your type is `struct rgb_data`, consider making the struct declaration a proper typedef.

Comment: When you say `>gcc -Wall testc o app`, don't you mean `>gcc -Wall test.c -o app` ? If so, then you run the app as `./app`.

Comment: C doesn't have `new`. I think you're mixing in a little C++.

Comment: yes, Lee Daniel Crocker i wanted to write this.

Comment: Mark Ransom, ah maybe, i discover the language, i will try to compile with g++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitmap file format is rather complicated. This is not the best way to learn C. It's better to start with something much simpler.

Having said that, the bitmap format starts with a bitmap header `BITMAPFILEHEADER` structure which is 14 bytes long, followed by `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure 40 bytes long. These structures are defined in `"Windows.h"`

You have to write in various information in these structures and write them to file before writing the actual pixels.

You can have 1, 4, 8, 16, 24, and 32-bit bitmap. This is an example to read a 32-bit bitmap. This code assumes `sizeof(short)` is 2, `sizeof(int)` is 4.

```
int main()
{
    int row, column;
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;
    int size = width * height * 4; //for 32-bit bitmap only

    char header[54] = { 0 };
    strcpy(header, "BM");
    memset(&header[2],  (int)(54 + size), 1);
    memset(&header[10], (int)54, 1);//always 54
    memset(&header[14], (int)40, 1);//always 40
    memset(&header[18], (int)width, 1);
    memset(&header[22], (int)height, 1);
    memset(&header[26], (short)1, 1);
    memset(&header[28], (short)32, 1);//32bit
    memset(&header[34], (int)size, 1);//pixel size

    unsigned char *pixels = malloc(size);
    for(row = height - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
        for(column = 0; column < width; column++) {
            int p = (row * width + column) * 4;
            pixels[p + 0] = 64; //blue
            pixels[p + 1] = 128;//green
            pixels[p + 2] = 192;//red
        }
    }

    FILE *fout = fopen("32bit.bmp", "wb");
    fwrite(header, 1, 54, fout);
    fwrite(pixels, 1, size, fout);
    free(pixels);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the first pixel is blue, followed by green and read. The last pixel is not used in 32-bit bitmap. Also the height goes from bottom to top. This is another odd feature of bitmap. 24-bit bitmaps are more complicated because they need padding. 8-bit and lower will need an additional palette.

```
struct rgb_data {
  float r, g, b;
};
```

`float` is not the right type for pixels. Each color goes from 0 to 255. This fits in `unsigned char`. You need instead

```
struct rgb_data {
  unsigned r, g, b, alpha;
};
```

The alpha is the extra byte for 32-bit bitmap (which we won't use). Notice the size of this structure is 4. You can allocate this as

```
struct rgb_data *rgb = malloc(size);
```

Now you can access the pixels as follows:

```
int p = (row * width + column);
rgb[p].r = 255;
rgb[p].g = 0;
rgb[p].b = 0;
...
fwrite(rgb, 4, width * height, fout);
```

Comment: okay, thanks ! i will test yoru script. i come from php/javascript/html/css and i would like to understand how to construct binary pictures and their formats what way should me to follow ? books/website ?

Comment: Book recommendations are off-topic according to website rules. You said you wanted to learn C, not web development. Bitmap format and the C language are rarely used in web development.

Comment: fwrite(header, 1, 54, fout) should be (header, 54, 1, fout), right? Same for second fwrite

Comment: @Jamie, Usage is `fwrite(const void* ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE* stream)`, in this case `fwrite(header, sizeof(char), 54, fout)` or just `fwrite(header, 1, 54, fout)`. Note, in other implementations `header` might be declared as a structure with size `54`, so you would write `fwrite(shdr, sizeof(shdr), 1, fout)`